# Is encryption a good method of protecting your java code?

Tags: java, reflection, encryption

I have a piece of software I don't want people to crack. Granted, I know nothing is truly uncrackable if you release it to the public. However, I want something that at least will make it a bit difficult to do so. I heard of encryption, and I thought it was a good idea. However, you have to call the defineClass method in order to begin the encryption (and you can interrupt this call). Though, I was thinking about using reflection and just calling it directly. Can that call still be interrupted? And is encryption a good method of protecting your program.

Comment: How is a legitimate user going to decrypt the code in order to run it?

Comment: The population I am releasing it to, consists of a decent amount of programmers (and a group that cracks software for the heck of it).

Comment: Yes, you can still interrupt all that and just "wait" for your code to decrypt the real code. No matter what you do, this will still be possible (and even easier in Java, since you could "simply" write your own JVM). If you don't want others to be able to *read* your code, don't give it to them: host it as a service and provide an API.

Comment: Basically - don't release Java executables to the public if you want to keep the code private.

Comment: That doesn't *just* apply to Java executables, it's true for all kinds of executables. But for Java it's even easier than for most other platforms (since the file format and machine specification is so well-defined and the "binary" format contains plenty of metadata).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is:

Not in java!

When you pack your programm into a runnable jar-file, all your classes are in there. but as byte code!

Reversing that byte-code to java file is possbile but not that easy to read.

Comment: What about writing your own class loader and loading the encrypted code from somewhere else than a regular jar file?

Comment: @Code: I'll redefine `ClassLoader.defineClass()` to dump the `byte[]` that's provided to it to the filesystem and I'll get all your tasty code on a platter (decrypted by your own clever classloader, no less).